# rails sanitize pops out of <p> tag

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sanitize, html-sanitizing

I have the following code

```
<p>
  <%= sanitize "<p>This is a test</p>" %>
</p>
```

I expected the sanitized html would show up between `<p></p>`.  However it produces.

```
<p>
      </p>
<p>This is a test</p>
```

When I change the enclosing `<p></p>` to `<div></div>`, the sanitized html shows up between `<div></div>` as I would expect.

Why does sanitizing html between `<p></p>` remove the sanitized html from the enclosing tag and place it after the enclosing tag?

How do I get the the sanitized html to show up in `<p></p>`?

Comment: So I thought I figured it out, but the the plot thickened. The chrome developer element tab, shows the sanitized html after the enclosing paragraph tag.  When I go to view source, the code looks fine (the sanitized html is within the paragraph tag).  When I try to access the node via JQuery in chrome developer console, it treats the node like in is not in the enclosing paragraph tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesting paragraph tags is not legal; the `<p>` tag only accepts [phrasing content tags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content).

This is why the Chrome dev tools show a changed order - the browser is correcting the mistake as good as it can and moves the inner `<p>` out and next to it.

Answer (score 0):

It is an HTML specification thing.  List are not suppose to be in paragraph tags.

More on this
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168723/unordered-list-in-a-paragraph-element#answer-7168757)

Answer (score 0):

The reason why `<p>` are not removed by sanitize methods is that `<p>` tag is in the list of default allowed tags.
Full list is:

```
del, dd, h3, address, big, sub, tt, a, ul, h4, cite, dfn, h5, small, kbd, code,
b, ins, img, h6, sup, pre, strong, blockquote, acronym, dt, br, p, div, samp,
li, ol, var, em, h1, i, abbr, h2, span, hr
```

More info: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper/sanitize

Comment: They do not expect the `<p>` tag to be removed. They expect it to appear as children (`<p><p></p></p>`), while Chrome instead renders it as siblings (`<p></p><p></p>`).