# Can I keep a list within the paragraph in kramdown?

Tags: markdown, kramdown

I need to be able to generate the following structure:

```
<p>
  Some text in the paragraph
  <ul>
    <li>item<li>
    <li>item<li>
  </ul>
  Some more text
</p>
```

How can I do this using [kramdown](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html)?
Is it possible?
I'm willing to use a reasonable amount of raw HTML if necessary, but nothing that duplicates kramdown functionality.

Answer (score 1):

HTML [doesn't allow lists to be inside paragraphs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-p-element) (for digestible explanations of this, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681481/should-ol-ul-be-inside-p-or-outside) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168723/unordered-list-in-a-paragraph-element)).

I would guess that the reason you want to do this is because you want the list to inherit the CSS characteristics of the `p` element. The easiest way to do this in kramdown is exactly what you'd do in the raw HTML - encase the paragraph and the list in another element, and then style that. For example, one way of doing this would be to use this:

```
<div id = "whatever">

Some text in the paragraph

* item
* item

Some more text

</div>
```

and then include

```
#whatever {
    property: value;
}
```

in your `general.css`, where those properties mimic those parts of the `p` element that you want.

Depending on what you have in your list items and what's in the subsequent paragraph, you may need to add kramdown's end-of-block marker (a caret, `^`) after the list to get the results you want. See these parts of the [kramdown](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#eob-marker) [documentation](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#lists) for more.